# SQL Server Client configuration via file

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to configure a SQL Server CLIENT (cliconfg) via file? I'm looking forward to something like tnsnames.ora in Oracle world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data about connection aliases is stored in the Registry, so either a `.reg` file or a script that updates registry would do. Updating the Registry can be done with `reg.exe` or Powershell.

The tricky parts are `cliconfg` syntax and the fact that 32/64 bit registry keys are not the same. That is,

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client
HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client
```

Take a look at [this article](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/tibor_karaszi/archive/2009/09/08/sql-client-config-32-and-64-bit.aspx) about 32/64 bit versions.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Unfortunately it requires to pass every client, but at least I can automate it a little...